# Can't get jQuery replacewith "img to figure" to be link (a href) sensitive (breaks)

Tags: jquery, image, figure, replacewith

after much research via Google and having read several stackoverflow posts, having tinkered with my jsfiddle for hours, I have hit a brick wall. Appreciate any pointers or help!

First Stackoverflow post myself here - hope I get this right. I love S&A, so helpful!

I have some jQuery understanding, but by far not good enough to solve this (apparently ;-()

**What I am trying to do (and ***jsFiddled***')**

- target all "img" in a div called "section-content"
- extract "src" and "alt" each
- wrap `<figure>` around the "imgs"
- IF there's a link (**.section-content a img**) to correctly display the link as part of         `<figure><a href="URL"><img src="IMAGE" alt="alt"/></a></figure>`
- add class ".section-image" to the `<figure>`
- strip all nonsense like width, height (some 500 posts, so clean code would be nice)
- strip old css class and styles from img

**Basically to transform:**

```
   <img width="174" height="174" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJPGfl3z2jsaZckTE4-TuK6bfvbTWk_8QNAStYN4eUWNYbkYeKMA" class="image-style" alt="description"/>
```

**TO**

```
   <figure class="section-image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJPGfl3z2jsaZckTE4-TuK6bfvbTWk_8QNAStYN4eUWNYbkYeKMA" alt="description"/></figure>
```

**AND if there's a link:**

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><img width="174" height="174" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJPGfl3z2jsaZckTE4-TuK6bfvbTWk_8QNAStYN4eUWNYbkYeKMA" class="image-style" alt="description"/></a>
```

**TO**

```
   <figure class="section-image"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJPGfl3z2jsaZckTE4-TuK6bfvbTWk_8QNAStYN4eUWNYbkYeKMA" alt="description"/></a></figure>
```

**What I have done so far**: - jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NGJYy/

**The problem I am facing:** 
- works for non-link images (without "a"), but I cannot add ".section-image" to the  (breaks?! oddly, tried `return $('<figure class="section-image">', {`
which it didn't like - images wouldnt be shown anymore then.

- IF A LINK EXISTS it just fails miserably and wraps the  around the  and then yet another time and returns the HREF as undefined.

**This works (thanks to your help!)**

```
$('.section-content * > img, .section-content * > a:has(img)').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />'); // will target elements to match your original question
  //$('.section-content > *').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />'); // will target all direct child elements
  //$('.section-content > img').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />'); // all direct IMG child elements
  //$('.section-content img').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />'); // all IMG descendants (including grand-children etc)
  //$('.section-content > img, .section-content > a').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />'); // all direct IMG and A child elements

$('.section-content img').each(function()
       {
       $(this).removeAttr('width');
       $(this).removeAttr('height');
       $(this).removeAttr('style');
       $(this).removeAttr('class');
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use jQuery's `wrap()` method?

```
$('.section-content > *').wrap('<figure class="section-image" />');
```

As of stripping specific attributes:

```
$('.section-content img').each(function()
       {
       $(this).removeAttr('width');
       $(this).removeAttr('height');
       $(this).removeAttr('style');
       });
```

**EDIT (as per your comment):**

```
  $('.section-content > img, .section-content > a:has(img)') // will target elements to match your original question
  $('.section-content > *') // will target all direct child elements
  $('.section-content > img') // all direct IMG child elements
  $('.section-content img') // all IMG descendants (including grand-children etc)
  $('.section-content > img, .section-content > a') // all direct IMG and A child elements
```

Comment: **hello haim770, this is already genius, so short, so sweet! How can I get it to target the _IMGs_ only?** I also have other classes that sit within .section-content, this means everything that is part of it now gets figure-wrapped. Much appreciate your help, great, thanks already!